# How to parse HTML into .txt format using C

Tags: html, c

I need to parse HTML into .txt format using C.

An example - it has to detect each

```
1. <p>
2. <tr>
3. <ul> etc...
```

and convert them into text (in a document)

Can somebody help please?

Comment: How much of parsing do you require? Is it only about searching occurance of each number in the file and altering them or the program has to decide whether to change the number or not based on some context?

Comment: The program needs only to convert texts into a webpage and converts them and save them into a document

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. HTML already is a text format. A small example of some HTML source code and what you want the resultant text file to be would clarify the question.

Comment: I need a program in C to convert a webpage into a .txt (Text Document). For exemple, in the program I need to enter the URL of the webpage and it has to convert it into a document.

Comment: Something like `lynx -dump http://example.com` ? A full blown textmode-browser is not a simple thing to do, so you might think about using a pipe.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to remove all the HTML tags leaving only the text. This is very simply done in any language using find/replace - in HTML tags MUST begin/end  with less than and greater than symbols. The sophistication you must introduce is what tags to replace with CR/LF and what bits like &nbsp; need replacing with spaces...  Over to you

Comment: The first step is to download the HTML source from its server. That is OS specific. In MSVC there are [`InternetOpenUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385098(v=vs.85).aspx) to make a connection and [`InternetReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385103(v=vs.85).aspx) to read in the data.

Comment: ...but in MSVC the standard library function `fopen` does not work for a remote URL.

Comment: but in my projet I do not have choice. I have to use fopen.

Comment: Please provide a sample of expected output (.txt file) given a sample input. Include that in your question to make it possible for others to answer.

Comment: a simple exemple is like as if we copy texts on a webpage and paste it in a word document.

Comment: Well *that* will include the markup formatting too - not relevant for a text file. The question is almost closed, still no example input/output or any attempt to write some code.

Comment: I already have a program written in C to parce an e-book into a word document, I have to adapt it to a webpages.

Comment: Have you thought of using an XSLT-processor? In XSLT, you can express rather simple how to deal with particular tags in an input stream...

Answer (score 0):

I think, the easiest way to download a `html` webpage in `c` is to use [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Assuming you have already set up your development environment, follow these steps:

1. Visit the *[download page](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)* of `libcurl` and download its latest version.
2. take a look at the *[install page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html)* and learn how to install the library. For Linux, the installation is pretty straight forward, just type `./configure && make && make install` in the terminal.
3. Download the [url2file.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curl/curl/master/docs/examples/url2file.c) example of `libcurl`. The `<curl/curl.h>` header file which is exposed in this file essentially provides necessary functions to let you communicate with the web server.
4. Next, compile the `url2file.c` using `gcc -o url2file url2file.c -lcurl`.
5. Finally, test `url2file` using `./url2file http://example.com`. The results will be stored in `page.out` file which is in plaintext.

NOTES:

1. You need to install the `libcurl` in order to be able to compile the `url2file.c` file, unless it will throw a `fatal error`.
2. If you have already installed the `curl` program on your machine, you can download webpages using `curl http://example.com > page.out` command in the terminal.
3. Also, `wget` lets you to download and store webpages:  `wget http://example.com`.
4. This answer stores a webpage as a pliantext. It doesn't perform any specific `html` tag processing.

Comment: The question is asking how to convert HTML to text, not how to make HTTP requests.

Comment: @duskwuff, here the exact comment about what rudstep asks for in the above comments: "... . For example, in the program I need to enter the URL of the webpage and it has to convert it into a document.". So, When you want to open a URL, you need to make HTTP calls. That's why I don't assume I have the HTTP pages saved in my drive and try to open them locally using `fopen`.